# registration failed on attempt to register a COM dll on windows server 2012 x64

Tags: php, android, dll, windows-server-2012, regsvr32

I am trying to register a 32 bit com.dll in sysWOW64

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32 xxx.dll

i have copied the dll in both the folders **SysWOW64** and **System32**

it shows error like

> The module "xxx.dll" failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at
>   the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary
>   or dependent .DLL files

if i check dependency walker there it shows some missing files what are these files?

> ATL110.DLL, MSVCR110.DLL, IESHIMS.DLL, MFPLAT.DLL, WLANAPI.DLL

these files are really necessary? i have downloaded redist files to overcome the problem but it failed still it shows the same error after installing the redist files

i have installed the same dll in **windows 7 x64** and it registered successfully system but not in **windows 2012 server x64**  what cause the error? how to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy paste those missing DLL to system 32 directory works, you can download it  from trusted sources, in my case i just copied it from my another win 7 x64 pc.